# Can not click this element using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to click this item, I tried many ways, by selenium webdriver, id by xpath in many ways but always receive a note that item not exist ??

```
<td id="td_MapToolsDrawByCoordinates" class="" onclick="MapTools.Click(&quot;DrawByCoordinates&quot;)" onmouseover="MapTools.MouseOver(&quot;DrawByCoordinates&quot;)" onmouseout="MapTools.MouseOut(&quot;DrawByCoordinates&quot;)" onmousemove="MapTools.MouseMove(event,'DrawByCoordinates');"><img name="MapTools_DrawByCoordinates" id="img_DrawByCoordinates" src="/RTAeNOCGIS/App_themes/rtaenoc/Images/Tools/FunctionalTools/startediting_off.png" alt=""></td>
```

my tries 
first by id

```
coordinate_icon = driver.find_element_by_id('td_MapToolsDrawByCoordinates')
Click_coordinate_icon = coordinate_icon.click()
```

by xpath

```
coordinate_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="td_MapToolsDrawByCoordinates"] and [@class="Container"]')
```

Comment: Can you show the things you've tried that don't work?

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include that in a code block - it's somewhat difficult to read in a comment... since `class=""` what do you think that's `and [@class="Container"]` is doing?

Comment: Using an ID should be good enough. The only case where it might cause problems is if there are more than one element that has that ID. That's clearly not the case here since Selenium can't find *any* element. The problem likely is 1. You need to add a wait or 2. The desired element is in an IFRAME. Check for both cases and come back and edit your post with the results of your investigations. Be sure to post the code you tried along with the error message.

Comment: Thanks guys, i solve it, i have to switch to the frame using ////////// driver.switch_to.frame("frame id name")